# Convert String to Double without BigDecimal type and without loss precision - java

Tags: java

I have a problem when converting a String to Double.

Decimals that remain to the right and are 0 are lost.

I have seen you can solve with the `BigDecimal`  type, but I don't want to use it.

Anyone know any way to fix it?

Regards,

---

This is an example(using `java.Text.DecimalFormat`):

```
Double d = 0.85;   // 0.85
DecimalFormat mf = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
String s = mf.format(d); // "0,850"

s = s.replace(',', '.'); // "0.850"

double conv = Double.parseDouble(s); //0.85
//String -> Double = 0.850???
```

Comment: `double` is a _number_.  Numbers have no concept of extra zeroes.  Your premise doesn't make sense.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I would like to convert String = "0.850" to Double = 0.850.

But they lost decimals (the zeros on the right) in the conversion.

Comment: There is no such thing as a double with trailing zeroes.  What problem are you trying to solve? See http://xyproblem.info

Comment: Sorry, I need to format with 3 decimals (0.850) this Double = 0.85 using DecimalFormat. The problem is DecimalFormat returns a String and not a Double.

Comment: @jmgc1982 it looks like that's what you're doing already in your code, without using `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Formatting is a property of how you display the number, not the number itself.  See the various format APIs for converting to string.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes! but if you see the "conv" variable at the end, you can see that the last zero disappears because I convert String to Double.

Comment: a double will not retain the unnecessary zero. If you want to print it out, then you need to format it again. If you are using the double as a number, you dont care about the trailing zeros

Comment: @jmgc1982 yes, that's been explained.  There is _no such thing_ as a trailing zero in a `double`, and no possible method will put it there.

Comment: @pczeus Thanks, but the problem is that Double variable is returned by a method of the class and is called from another class and this must print the value (0.850) returned with a System.out.print().

Comment: Then format the output..

Comment: @pczeus 
yes, but the class that calls the method can't have the import java.text.DecimalFormat, and therefore I can't apply the format in print(). This is the big problem!